# generate template in vim

Tags: templates, vim

I have this very often that I quickly want to test something (html, css or javascript), so I create a small test file like this:

```
<doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        </style>
        <script>
        </script>
    <head>

    <body>
    </body>
<html>
```

I'm using VIM, and I was wondering if it is possible to add something somewhere, with the result that VIM can generate this template for me?

Comment: Snipmate is the business for this sort of thing! See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/879590/78845

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, you can.

1) create a file, with that content, say, `foo.html`

2) create a mapping E.g `nnoremap <F9> :r /path/to/foo.html<cr>`

3) when you want to get that template, press `<F9>` in normal mode. The content of your foo.html will be inserted into your current buffer.

Comment: thnx. I've add the command to .vimrc, and when I press F9 it shows the command (which is: r /path/to/foo.html). When I press <enter> the content is inserted. This is perfect, but is it possible to have it inserted without the <enter> ?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri did you also put the `<cr>` in your mapping? check my `2) create....` line carefully.

Comment: thats it, thnx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create base template files as described in the answer by @Kent and then to write a set of Vim macros to load and "process" the templates which may include invoking external commands -- most useful on Unix/Linux/Mac OS X platforms. The macros themselves may be added to your `.vimrc` or `.viminfo` files so that they are loaded every time you start Vim. For more information, see:

> [Macros](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros)