# automatic try/catch statements in vim

Tags: vim, automation, try-catch

I find myself typing something like

```
class Foo{
   myFancyType bar();
}

myFancyType Foo::bar()
{
    try{
        //do some stuff
    }
    catch(myFavoriteExceptionType &e){
        std::cerr<<e.what()<<std::endl;
        throw myFavoriteExceptionType("Foo::bar() failed");
    }
}
```

very, very, VERY, often.

I am currently working with vim and my search was unsuccessfull. Is there some plugin that will automate the nasty repetitive task of manually inserting the try/catch statement when defining a function?

Comment: hum… it's actually not _really_ off-topic, as the OP has identified an issue with his vim editing process, and is looking for a solution. I was also updating my answer to give the OP a way of doing it without a plugin, but only with vim's internals (when I ran out of batteries) ☺

Comment: Unfortunately, many think that questions regarding configuration of programming tools are not welcomed on SO. They'd rather scatter the community that masters those tools on several sites :(

BTW, the manual solution could indeed be given, but this won't provide the best end-user experience when there already exist complex plugins that solve the need expressed by the OP -- when the plugins are complex, it's likely the need isn't that trivial or entirely formulated (e.g. nobody wants `try` to be expanded within string or comment contexts ; some would want `{` on new lines, other not, etc)

Comment: well, I'd vote for this to be a duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334/how-to-create-short-snippets-in-vim :-) or maybe otherwise moved to vi SE! but anyway ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's indeed a plugin you can use to that end, it's called snipmate and has been inspired by the textmate automatic snippet insertion. It's usually triggerd using the `tab` key, but that can be set to any other leader keystroke. The way it works is pretty simple: given you've got a snippet defined for the try catch, you just write in insert mode `try<tab>` and it'll insert the try catch construct. Successive tabs will have you jump to the different parts of the snippet that need your input (like what you catch, how you want to deal with it, and finally the tried code).

- https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate

Another option for you would be to try UltiSnips that tries to be smarter than snipmate, as you can have some code that runs when resolving the snippet.

- https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips
- https://medium.com/brigade-engineering/sharpen-your-vim-with-snippets-767b693886db#.fctyvg97p

you can also make snippets without any plugins. You can use either `map` for doing from normal mode, or `abbrev` for doing it from insert mode:

```
map <leader>st maotry {<CR>} catch (my_exception err) {<CR>std::cerr<<e.what()<<std::endl;<CR>throw myFavoriteExceptionType("Foo::bar() failed");<CR>}<ESC>='a'ao
```

which will setup a mark (`ma`), start editing on the next line (`o`) write the template code up until `<ESC>`. Then it will align the code starting at the mark (`='a`), and finally jump at the mark to start editing the `try {}` block.

Or you can do the same with abbrev:

```
iabbrev try <C-o>matry {<CR>} catch (my_exception err) {<CR>std::cerr<<e.what()<<std::endl;<CR>throw myFavoriteExceptionType("Foo::bar() failed");<CR>}<ESC>='a'ao
```

which will do the same but while you're typing in insert mode.

HTH

Comment: The mapping and abbreviation should be `<buffer>`-local and `nore` (to avoid issues with bracketing plugins). Moreover I suspect the mapping won't work in visual mode, it should explicitly be `nnoremap`. Then the catch should be with a const-reference, but this is another issue unrelated to vim :)

Answer (score 0):

In [lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp), I provide (context-sensitive) (insert-mode) abbreviations on `try` and `catch`, mappings can can surround a selection with `try{...}catch{}` or with `catch(){...}`, and snippets that can do both.

Snippets, abbreviations, and mappings for the other C and C++ control-statements are also provided.

PS: catching exceptions at every step is usually and very bad pattern in C++ (in and other languages with exceptions). See [E.17 and E.18 in CppCoreGuidelines.](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Re-not-always) -- *E.17: Don't try to catch every exception in every function* ; *E.18: Minimize the use of explicit try/catch*